# Lift values on Applicative

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

This question is based on the [scala cats library](http://typelevel.org/cats/), but I guess could apply to `scalaz` or general functional programming.

I'm trying the [cats exercises](https://www.scala-exercises.org/cats/apply) and I thought of the following functionality with `Applicative`: Is there a function with the following signature and if so, what's it's name?

```
def foo[A[_]: Applicative, B, C, D](x: B, y: C)(f: (A[B], A[C]) => A[D]): A[D]
```

That is, if I have a function lying around that takes two `Applicative` instances and produces a third as result (`f`), I want to apply it to 2 values `x` and `y` without having to wrap it in an `Applicative` myself with `pure`. I can easily implement it myself like:

```
def pureMap[A[_]: Applicative, B, C, D](x: B, y: C)(f: (A[B], A[C]) => A[D]): A[D] = {
  val ap = Applicative[A]
  f(ap.pure(x), ap.pure(y))
}
```

but it looked like something that might exist already and I couldn't find anything. (`pureMap` sounded like a reasonable name).

An example would be, if I already had a function in a validation library like:

```
def div(ox: Option[Int], oy: Option[Int]): Option[Int] = 
  for {
    x <- ox
    y <- oy
    if y != 0
  } yield x / y
```

, then I would want to use it like:

```
val z:Option[Int] = pureMap(2,0)(div)
```

Comment: The `A[_]`s on the left side of the function arrow look a little odd. What's an example of an `f` that makes this necessary?

Comment: @TravisBrown, added an example

Comment: But that example could easily be rewritten as `(Int, Int) => Option[Int]` and then lifted to `Option` as needed, and in my experience that's generally the case.

Comment: I know, It's just an hypothetical available function I'd want to reuse as it is. The question was, is there such thing as `pureMap` already? Never said I'd need it very often :)

Comment: Fair enough! Then afaik the answer is "no". :)